# How to get autocompletion coding support writing winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have been writing Java for a long time using Eclipse, now trying to switch to C++ in Visual Studio. From Eclipse/Java I know such auto-complete features: I write

```
bar = Foo.valueOf(x);
bar.doSomething(y, z);
```

and Eclipse offers me both to `import` whatever `Foo` I might mean, and declare `bar` as local variable, field, or parameter. Or create the function `doSomething()` with the appropriate signature, auto-adding missing imports to `Foo`. I am missing a corresponding feature on Visual Studio 2015, which does for example

- add the corresponding `#include` and `#pragma comment(lib,` statements,
- add these statements in a clear order, so that they work as expected (something like *organize imports*),
- add namespace statements
- declare variables, fields, and parameters on click/keypress
- create function bodies, adding the corresponding foreward declarations to the respective header files, adding missing includes required by the declaration
- …

The only things that I found so far is the “add class” dialog. When writing an unknown function name, right clicking and choosing “quick actions and refactorings” → Create declaration / definition, a window opens with the text

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]);
```

but it does not create a definition for that function.

**Are there some better “save me typing work” functions available in Visual Studio 15, and if yes, how can I benefit from them?** Is there another way I could go, such as writing the C++ program (Windows API) in an other IDE (are there any for Winapi C++ which do better?)

Comment: Recommendations of software or library (in this case plugin for VS) is off-topic. Voted to close as such.

Comment: I didn’t know that there are plug-ins for VS. Perhaps you want to make your comment an answer as it is helpful.

Comment: You might look at e.g. Resharper, (https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html). I haven't used it but it's often recommended. Looks like it's not free.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Do you want to make your comment, that VS supports plug-ins, an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) by JetBrains does what you are asking for more or less. It will notice an error in your code, whether it being that something wasn't fully initialized, or something that you needed to include, or a host of other things.

It is not free though, but you can try it on a 30 day trial.

I don't know of an IDE that supports winapi functions like you're asking though. I think you'll just have to pick your favorite IDE and get used to it.

Comment: Resharper hardly does anything the OP is asking for. [Visual Assist](http://wholetomato.com/) does some of the things, the OP needs, but not all. It doesn't automatically add `#include` directives, for example, but offers auto completion for them. I doubt any tool can provide the features requested, due to the ambiguous nature of native programming languages like C or C++.

Comment: I know that Resharper doesn't provide everything that OP is asking for, but it's the closest plugin that I know of that offers some of what OP wants. I've never heard of Visual Assist, would you say it's better than Resharper, or does it just offer different things?

Comment: Visual Assist has been directed towards C/C++ from day one (and that is almost 2 decades ago). ReSharper, on the other hand, started out with a focus on .NET development. For native development, Visual Assist has always been the first option to consider. It does some of the things the OP is looking for (like implement function stubs from declarations), but doesn't do things it cannot safely do (like adding or reordering `#include` directives).

Comment: @IInspectable Do you want to make your comment an answer?